# react router, curious as to how it does url navigation without hashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

Using create react app you can wire up a router and it navigates **without a #**, as in index/page1 ,I thought the browser would auto send that to a server as the client only traps # changes, this is a question out of pure curiosity, so how does react do proper url navigation  I'm using create react app with yarn I guess it uses a node webserver of some type. how about when we host this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the History API article on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API):

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:
>
> ```
> var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
> history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
> ```
>
> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html,
>   but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that
>   bar.html exists.

<sup>(by [Mozilla Contributors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API$history), licensed under [CC-BY-SA 2.5](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/))</sup>

So, using `history.pushState` you can change the location in the URL bar without actually performing a navigation. (However, I believe that if the user reloads the page the browser will request the new URL from the server, so the server should still return an appropriate page for the new URL.)